# How to change CSS li tag in Bootstrap3 navigation when in and out or responsive view?

Tags: css, navigation, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to change the bootstrap3 navigation height of the parent (li a) tags but in both instances (desktop and mobile). In desktop mode the parent li tags are very tall but in mobile mode the li tag needs to be normal height.

**What it should do:**
[what I would like](http://tinypic.com/r/332xu09/5)

**What it is doing:**
[not working example](http://tinypic.com/r/2v3mqv5/5)

**Here is the CSS that I am Using**

```
/*-- targeted li a tag  --*/
.nav > li > a { padding: 50px 20px 20px 20px; }

/*-- visual --*/
.navbar-nav > li > a { font-weight: bold; color: #868686; text-transform: uppercase; }
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus { background-color: #373D39; color: #fff; }
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus { background-color: #373D39; color: #fff; }
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus { background-color: #373D39; color: #fff; }
```

**Here is the CSS that I tried** - I just need help in this area of targeting the (li a) in mobile mode

```
/*-- I am trying to target the menu in mobile mode (collapsed) but if I do this it changes the desktop mode as well   --*/
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse li a, .navbar-default .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > li a { padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px }
```

**Here is my Demo HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
<div class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <<!--span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span-->
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href= "#">Menu</a>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav text-left">
        <li class=" active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class=" dropdown "><a href="#" id="drop1"  data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" >About <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul  role="menu" class="dropdown-menu"  aria-labelledby="drop1">
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Overview</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Team Bios</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Customers</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Careers</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap your custom nav CSS in a media query..

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {

/*-- targeted li a tag  --*/
.nav > li > a { padding: 50px 20px 20px 20px; }

/*-- visual --*/
.navbar-nav > li > a { font-weight: bold; color: #868686; text-transform: uppercase; }
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus { background-color: #373D39; color: #fff; }
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus { background-color: #373D39; color: #fff; }
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus { background-color: #373D39; color: #fff; }

}
```

So that only the default (normal li height) will appear on mobile.

**Working demo**: http://bootply.com/92228

P.S. - If you only want to keep the custom have colors / background on mobile, you can just wrap the custom `li > a` padding in the @media query..

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {

  /*-- targeted li a tag  --*/
  .nav > li > a { padding: 50px 20px 20px 20px; }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I should really need to learn to follow the KISS anagram. Thanks again.